# General formula for $\sin^{-1}(m \sin (nx))$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any general formula for $\sin^{-1}(m \sin (nx))$?

(I'm not sure whether or not it does matter, but) in my particular application, $m>>1$, $n=2$, and $x$ may arbitrarily vary.

Comment: You cannot have $m>1.$ At most $m=1.$ Otherwise you're no longer dealing with real values.

Comment: And what do you mean by general formula? Isn't this formula enough? Given appropriate values of the variables, can't you evaluate the function?

Comment: @Allawonder: This formula is a part of the dynamics of a system for which I need to design a controller. To do so and to study the stability of the system, I need to approximate this term. Fourier or Taylor series would be an option, though I thought a better closed representation may exist.

Comment: What I'm trying to get is what you mean by *better closed form.* Do you want to express it in terms of other functions, like what? Surely this can never be equal to any polynomial. I think you may get a series in powers of $\sin nx,$ which you may convert to a power series if you want. To do that you only need look up the series expansion of the arcsine and its interval of validity, or just integrate the series for $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=(1-x^2)^{-1/2},$$ which you may obtain by the binomial theorem.

Comment: If $m=2, n=2, x=\pi/4$ then your expression is $\pi/2-i1.31695...$ Are you sure you want that?